# Add TSDoc to nested parameters of a function callback in .d.ts

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How would I add TSDoc to parameters of a function's callback?

I'm trying to create `.d.ts` typings for a certain open-source JavaScript NPM module.

I've got this class event method declared:

```js
declare class ClassName {
  /**
  * Emitted when...
  * 
  * @param event "eventName"
  * @param listener Function that will be emitted with this event.
  */
  on(
    event: 'eventName', 
    listener: (tag: string, callback: (err: string, time: number, key: string) => void) => void
  ): this;
}
```

Example usage of this method is:

```js
const class = new ClassName();

class.on('eventName', function(tag, callback) {
    const time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    callback(null, time, getKey(time, tag));
});
```

When I hover in my IDE over the `.on` it shows the comments for `event` and `listener` (which is expected).

But how would I add more doc comments (their meaning and explanation) for those nested params (`tag`, `callback`) and for those even more nested params (`err`, `time`, `key`) in order to see the comments when I would hover over `tag` and `callback` in the example?